# Kendo scheduler, newly created object ID is not saved in the datasource

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I tried to create an item on the API and return a value with new 'ScheduleID', When I did a trace, API does return a new ScheduleID in the newly created object, but ScheduleID is never saved in the dataSource. Anyone know why?

```
vm.schedulerOptions = {
  date: new Date(classStartDate.getUTCFullYear(), classStartDate.getUTCMonth(), classStartDate.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0),
  height: 600,
  views: [
    "day",
    {type: "week", selected: true},
  ],

  dataSource: {
    transport: {
      read: function (options) {
        if ($stateParams.classId) {
          scheduleDf.getScheduleByClassId($stateParams.classId).success(function (result) {
            options.success(result);
          }).error(function (err) {
            options.error(err);
          })
        } else if ($stateParams.sectionId) {
          scheduleDf.getScheduleBySectionId($stateParams.sectionId).success(function (result) {
            options.success(result);
          }).error(function (err) {
            options.error(err);
          })
        }
      },
      create: function (options) {
        options.data.ClassId = classInfor.data[0].ClassID;
        options.data.AtLocationId = vm.locationCb.dataItem().LocationID;
        options.data.ConfirmationNumber = vm.ConfirmationNumber;
        scheduleDf.createSchedule(options.data).success(function (result) {
          //vm.grid.dataSource.read();
          options.success(result);
        }).error(function (err) {
          options.error(err);
        })
      },
      update: function (options) {
        if (!fromMovingBar) {
          options.data.AtLocationId = vm.locationCb.dataItem().LocationID;
          fromMovingBar = false;
        }
        scheduleDf.updateSchedule(options.data).success(function (result) {
          vm.grid.dataSource.read();
          options.success(result);
        }).error(function (err) {
          options.error(err);
        })
      },
      destroy: function (options) {
        scheduleDf.deleteSchedule(options.data.ScheduleID).success(function (result) {
          vm.grid.dataSource.read();
          options.success();
        }).error(function (err) {
          options.error(err);
        })
      }
    },
    schema: {

      model: {
        id: "ScheduleID",

        fields: {

          start: {type: "date", from: "FromTime"},
          end: {type: "date", from: "ToTime"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  editable: {
    template: '<div ng-include="' + "'/schedule/_schedule_editor.html'" + '"></div>',
    create: false
  },
  edit: function (e) {
    e.container.data("kendoWindow").center();
    e.container.find(".k-edit-form-container").width("auto");
    e.container.data("kendoWindow").wrapper.css({width: 700});
  },
  moveEnd: function (e) {
    fromMovingBar = true;
  },
  resizeEnd: function (e) {
    fromMovingBar = true;
  },
  resources: [{
    field: 'SessionTypeID',
    dataColorField: 'ColorCode',
    dataValueField: 'SessionTypeID',
    dataTextField: 'SessionTypeName',
    dataSource: sessionTypes.data
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for current behavior is that the response from the server is not formatted the same way as the "read" request. You should try to insert the record inside array. For more info you can check this [help article.](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/troubleshooting)

Also I notice that the Scheduler have no timezone option set. Please note that the **timezone option is highly recommended to be set** - for more details you can check the **[new Timezones help article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/timezones)**.